# How to print out after a looped user input in java?

Tags: java

My code looks like this so far:

```
public class CatWorld {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Scanner getLine = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userSays;

        //ARRAY:
        int [] CatArray;
        CatArray = new int [5];

        //ARRAY-POWERED LOOP:
        for (int i=0; i < CatArray.length; i ++) {

            //OPTIONAL PROMPT:
            System.out.println ("Wow! A brand new cat! What's its name?");

            //Mandatory below
            userSays = getLine.next();
            Cat babyCat = new Cat(userSays);
            System.out.println ("The new cat's name is "
                                + babyCat.getcatName() + "!");
        }
    }
}
```

And my constructor looks like this:

```
public class Cat {
    String catName = "Billybob";

    public Cat (String Name) { //Can also be birthName
        catName = Name;
    }

    public String getcatName(){
        return catName;
    }
}
```

What happens when I run it is that it outputs right after I input the name. How would I go about outputting them all after the 5 name inputs?

Comment: to clarify, how do I recall all the names of the kittens after the loop is finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tested and works**

Change your code in you `main` method to this:

```
Scanner getLine = new Scanner(System.in);
String userSays;

Cat[] catList = new Cat[5]; // create array of 5 cats

int catCount = 0;

// loop to get all the user input for the cats
for (Cat cat : catList) // for each cat in cat array (5 cats)
{
    System.out.println("Wow! A brand new cat! What's its name?");

    userSays = getLine.next(); // get the cat name

    catList[catCount] = new Cat(userSays); // set this cat in the cat array to be
                                           // the user input

    catCount++; // + the catCount, so the next cat in the cat array is focused on
}

// loop to display all of the cats back to the console
for (Cat cat : catList) // for each cat in the cat array
{
    // display the cat's name in this iteration of the cat array
    System.out.println ("The new cat's name is " + cat.getcatName() + "!");
}
```

Comment: Where do I put the i?

Comment: @K-Java-K dont simply copy the answer. Go through on it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the `Cat`s somehow.

```
List<Cat> catList = new ArrayList<Cat>();

// Ask for cat names, and insert cat objects into list
```

then at the end,

```
for (Cat cat : catList) {
  // print whatever you want about the cats.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to store your cat in the array you created. Then you loop and you show them in console.

```
Cat[] catArray = new Cat[5];
for (int i=0; i < catArray.length; i ++){
     System.out.println ("Wow! A brand new cat! What's its name?");
     userSays = getLine.next();
     catArray[i] = new Cat(userSays);
}
```

Then you loop again:

```
for (int i=0; i < catArray.length; i ++){
     System.out.println ("The new cat's name is "
             +catArray[i].getcatName() + "!");    
}
```

By the way, you should follow java code conventions variable's name starts with lower-case.

Comment: I just started learning java, and my teacher doesn't exactly explain it. When I put in your code, it gives me an error at the CatArray[i]: required: int found: Cat

Comment: Use String[] CatArray = new String[5]; not int

Comment: @K-Java-K sorry i update answer, you have to define your array like `Cat[]`

Answer (score 0):

```
 int [] CatArray;
 Cat[] catName = new String[5]; // Get cat names
 CatArray = new int [5];
    //ARRAY-POWERED LOOP:
 for (int i=0; i < CatArray.length; i ++){
    //OPTIONAL PROMPT:
    System.out.println ("Wow! A brand new cat! What's its name?");
    //Mandatory below
    userSays = getLine.next();

    catName[i] = new Cat(userSays);

 }

 for(int i = 0; i < catName.size; i++) {
      System.out.println ("The new cat's name is "
         catName[i].getcatName() + "!");

 }
```